# Problem with inversion of the system $u=\frac{\cos\theta}{1-t\cos\theta}$, $v=\frac{\sin\theta}{1+t\sin\theta}$.

Tags: trigonometry

I'm solving some exercises in differential geometry and I came across this system.

> $$u=\frac{\cos\theta}{1-t\cos\theta}~~~;~~~v=\frac{\sin\theta}{1+t\sin\theta}$$

I want to solve it in order to replace $\sin\theta+\cos\theta$ and $t$ in terms of $u$ and $v$, but I cannot find a way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to invert each equality and then you can solve them for $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$. Then, use $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta =1$ to get rid of $\theta$ and solve for $t$. Having $t$ as a function of $u$ and $v$, you can find $\sin\theta+\cos\theta$ easily.

Comment: Easily?
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 t_1=-\frac{-u+v+\sqrt{4 v^2 u^2+u^2+2 v u+4 v \sqrt{u^2+2 v u+\left(u^2+1\right) v^2} u+v^2}}{2 u v} \\
 t_2=\frac{u-v+\sqrt{4 v^2 u^2+u^2+2 v u+4 v \sqrt{u^2+2 v u+\left(u^2+1\right) v^2} u+v^2}}{2 u v} \\
 t_3=-\frac{-u+v+\sqrt{(u-v)^2+4 u v \left(u v-\sqrt{\left(v^2+1\right) u^2+2 v u+v^2}+1\right)}}{2 u v} \\
 t_4=\frac{u-v+\sqrt{(u-v)^2+4 u v \left(u v-\sqrt{\left(v^2+1\right) u^2+2 v u+v^2}+1\right)}}{2 u v} \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: I mean, there is no theoretical difficulty. Although it is hard to calculate in practice.

Answer (score 3):

You have:

$$\cos \theta=\frac{u}{1+ut}\text{ and }\sin \theta=\frac{v}{1-vt}$$

Now use $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2 \theta=1$.

$$\frac{u^2}{(1+ut)^2}+\frac{v^2}{(1-vt)^2}=1$$

Solving the above equation you will get equation in $t$ and then you can find $t$ as a function of $u$ and $v$